# Python C API: PyDateTime_FromTimestamp causes segmentation fault

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, python-datetime

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7252464/3429266) to call `PyDateTime_FromTimestamp` to create a `datetime` object in C++. But I got a `Segmentation fault` when `PyDateTime_FromTimestamp` is called.

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <python3.6/Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <python3.6/datetime.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

static PyObject *iGetDateTime_PyFn(PyObject *Py_UNUSED(self), PyObject *Py_UNUSED(args)) {
    static double doubleValue = 1314761451;
    PyObject *floatObj = NULL;
    PyObject *timeTuple = NULL;
    PyObject *dateTime = NULL;
    floatObj = PyFloat_FromDouble(doubleValue);
    timeTuple = Py_BuildValue("(O)", floatObj);
    printf("timeTuple = %08x\n", (unsigned int)(long long)timeTuple);
    printf("PyTuple_Check(timeTuple) = %d\n", PyTuple_Check(timeTuple));
    dateTime = PyDateTime_FromTimestamp(timeTuple);
    printf("ready to return\n");
    return dateTime;
}

static PyMethodDef all_methods[] = {
    { "get_datetime", iGetDateTime_PyFn, METH_VARARGS, NULL },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

static struct PyModuleDef main_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "cpp",
    NULL,
    -1,
    all_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_cpp(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&main_module);
}
```

I compiled with this command:

```
g++ --shared -fPIC -o cpp.so t1.cpp
```

My `g++` version is `7.3.0`.

In python, I execute:

```
import cpp
print(cpp.get_datetime())
```

And I get the following printed:

```
timeTuple = a7934358
PyTuple_Check(timeTuple) = 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As we can see the `timeTuple` is successfully constructed and it is checked as a `tuple`. But we cannot get to the `return` sentence.

Comment: Please add the `ldd cpp.so` command output, and also in your *Python* script add `import sys`; `print(sys.version)`, and paste its output then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (3.6) cpython/Include/datetime.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Include/datetime.h) (*${PYTHON_SRC_DIR}/Include/datetime.h*):

1. *PyDateTime_FromTimestamp* is a *preprocessor **macro***:

   ```c
   #define PyDateTime_FromTimestamp(args) \
       PyDateTimeAPI->DateTime_FromTimestamp( \
           (PyObject*) (PyDateTimeAPI->DateTimeType), args, NULL)
   ```
2. *PyDateTimeAPI* is initialized to *NULL* (earlier in file)

   ```c
   static PyDateTime_CAPI *PyDateTimeAPI = NULL;
   ```

resulting in *segfault* (*Access Violation*) when invoking the macro.

the fix requires initializing *PyDateTimeAPI* via the ***PyDateTime_IMPORT*** macro.

```c
#define PyDateTime_IMPORT \
    PyDateTimeAPI = (PyDateTime_CAPI *)PyCapsule_Import(PyDateTime_CAPSULE_NAME, 0)
```

Initially, I discovered this while browsing the code (and I did it in the *getDateTimePyFn* function), then I came across [[Python 3.Docs]: DateTime Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/datetime.html) (**emphasis** is mine)

> Before using any of these functions, the header file `datetime.h` must be included in your source (note that this is not included by `Python.h`), and **the macro *PyDateTime_IMPORT* must be invoked, usually as part of the module initialization function**.

I modified your code, and I will exemplify on *Win* (as it'e easier for me, and the behavior is reproducible).

*cpp.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <datetime.h>

#define MOD_NAME "cpp"


static double doubleValue = 1314761451;

static PyObject *getDateTimePyFn(PyObject *Py_UNUSED(self), PyObject *Py_UNUSED(args)) {
    PyObject *floatObj = NULL,
        *timeTuple = NULL,
        *dateTime = NULL;
    floatObj = PyFloat_FromDouble(doubleValue);
    if (!floatObj)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    timeTuple = Py_BuildValue("(O)", floatObj);
    Py_XDECREF(floatObj);
    if (!timeTuple)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    dateTime = PyDateTime_FromTimestamp(timeTuple);
    Py_XDECREF(timeTuple);
    return dateTime;
}


static PyMethodDef all_methods[] = {
    { "get_datetime", getDateTimePyFn, METH_VARARGS, NULL },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};


static struct PyModuleDef main_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    MOD_NAME,
    NULL,
    -1,
    all_methods
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_cpp(void) {
    PyDateTime_IMPORT;  // @TODO - cfati: !!! This initializes the struct containing the function pointer !!!
    return PyModule_Create(&main_module);
}
```

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import cpp


def main():
    print("cpp.get_datetime returned: {:}".format(cpp.get_datetime()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("Done.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055903897]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x64
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code.py
> cpp.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL /MD /I"c:\Install\x64\Python\Python\03.06.08\include" cpp.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\x64\Python\Python\03.06.08\libs" /OUT:cpp.pyd
> cpp.c
>    Creating library cpp.lib and object cpp.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code.py
> cpp.c
> cpp.exp
> cpp.lib
> cpp.obj
> cpp.pyd
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> cpp.get_datetime returned: 2011-08-31 06:30:51
> Done.
> ```

Comment: @cosmozhang: did this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @CristiFati. This solved my problem. It was my fault that I did not read the doc carefully.

Comment: Then please mark the answer as a solution to your question, so others can see it too.